# Aranyaka - What quests do I have to complete to unlock the tree in Sumeru?

Tags: genshin-impact

Starting from version 3.0 with Sumeru release, the world quest Aranyaka is a big cluster of quest lines when you enter Part II of it (Dream Nursery)

The only quest line I have finished from part II is the one with the infamous Aranakin and his friends (I now have the whithered Kusava)

Do I have to finish all of Dream Nursery to unlock Sumeru's "tree" where I can submit my dendro sigils? Or do I have to finish a specific Dream Nursery quest line? Or worse, do I have to finish Part III and/or Part IV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this website article](https://www.eurogamer.net/genshin-impact-how-to-unlock-tree-of-dreams-vanarana-rewards-9026#section-1)

> once you complete 'The World of Aranara' part of 'Aranyaka Part 2', you will then receive the 'Trees and Dreams' Word Quest automatically

Comment: "Trees and Dreams" is it then? Thanks a lot